# Is this a linear model?

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear

[image: formula]

---

mpg = mileage per gallon and
hp = horsepower

---

Why is this model a linear model despite having a square of horsepower in it?

Comment: Models are called linear when they are a linear function of the coefficients.

Comment: Ok i got the answer. For the model to be linear it needs to be linear in terms of parameters not the predictors. Here betas are parameters and horsepower is predictor

Comment: I'm voting to close this question topic because the OP answered it in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got the answer. For the model to be linear it needs to be linear in terms of parameters not the predictors. Here betas are parameters and horsepower is predictor

Answer (score 1):

In order to explain this, I would consider the following quadratic function.

[image]

By comparing this function with your function, `x1` would be similar to your `hp` (horsepower).

Actually what we have really done is, we have created a new feature `x2` where

[image]

By plugging this new feature to the above hypothesis we get the following function which is just like a linear model

[image]

Comment: i have posted the correct answer below.